# Win10 doesn't respect pagefile settings for other disks than C:

Tags: windows-10, pagefile, swap-file

I tried to move my pagefile off from C: to another disk, D:. I set my preferences in *Start > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Performance > Advanced > Virtual Memory*. I have set

```
C:  100-1000MB   (They advice to leave at least minimal page file on C:.)
D:  100-16000MB
```

However, Win10 doesn't create pagefile.sys on D:, which often results in apps crashing because of out-of-memory. (It rarely does create it, but mostly it doesn't.)

This used to work in the past. Has anything changed in this regard in the last Win10 updates? Could this be caused by Group policy? If this should work, how can I determine the cause of the problem? In the Event Viewer I found nothing suspicious.

Configuration: Win10 Enterprise, version 20H2 (10.0.19042), there is plenty of space on the disks.

Comment: “This used to work in the past. Has anything changed in this regard in the last Win10 updates?” - Microsoft hasn’t made any announcement that they changed anything with the page file so that’s extremely unlikely (pigs learning how to fly has a greater chance of happening)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a page file on C at all, you can have it on just D with no problems. Since you have it set to only 1GB on C, I recommend just removing it from C and have D handle the page file. I have my system setup that way. I have 2 SSDs, OS is installed on 1 and the paging file on 2. However, it should be able to do fine using both, you may be getting that out-of-memory crash because it does use up all the available memory on both C & D, you should have it set to a System Managed size on one of the drives to ensure you never hit a cap, short of running out of drive space.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you're right, paging file on C: is not necessary. But if you try to disable it, you'll get a warning that "when a system error occurs, Windows might not record details that could help identify the problem". In Win7, pagefile on D: worked; in Win10 this worked, I think, half a year ago.